# Python how to link function if statements to Tkinter Label?

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import glob
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
import datetime
import sys
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SIGN OFF")
root.minsize(840, 800)
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

username = Label(mainframe, text = "Username").pack()
usr = Entry(mainframe).pack()
password = Label(mainframe, text = "Password").pack()
pwd = Entry(mainframe).pack()
submit = Button(mainframe, text = "Log in").pack()


def askUser():
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    if username == "Ed" and password == "true":
        app()
    if username == "buxton" and password == "logix":
        app()
    else:
        root.destroy()


root.mainloop()
```

This will prompt me a window with username and password.

How can I link the input of Username from the displayed window to `askUser()` function Username and vice versa with Password?

If I use just this piece of code and run it:

```
def askUser():
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    if username == "Ed" and password == "true":
        app()
    if username == "buxton" and password == "logix":
        app()
    else:
        print("failed")
```

Command prompt will be the main screen of inputting password and usernames, but I need to get it on a window.

It's a small project, if anyone has any comments about the security about this, I am not really concerned but open for suggestions! :)

Comment: first: don't do `usr = Entry().pack()` because it assings `None` instead of `Entry` to `usr` because `pack()` returns always `None` and then you don't have access to `Entry` to get user name and its password. You have to do it in two steps `usr = Entry()` and `usr.pack()`

Comment: Made the edit, Im I on the right line with you?

Comment: don't change code in question because later it will not fit to answer(s). Append new code with changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: don't do

```
  usr = Entry().pack()
```

because it assings `None` to `usr` because `pack()` always returns `None` and then you don't have access to `Entry` to get user name and its password. You have to do it in two steps

```
 usr = Entry()
 usr.pack()
```

For labels  and button you can even skip variables because you will not need them.

---

Second: you can access function to button using `command=function_name`. It has to be name without `()` (so called `"callback"`).

```
tk.Button(mainframe, text="Log in", command=ask_user)
```

When you click button then `mainloop` will run `ask_user()`

And inside `ask_user` you can get values from `Entry` using `.get()`

```
    username = usr.get()
    password = pwd.get()
```

---

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def ask_user():
    username = usr.get()
    password = pwd.get()

    if username == "Ed" and password == "true":
        app()
    if username == "buxton" and password == "logix":
        app()
    else:
        root.destroy()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

tk.Label(mainframe, text="Username").pack()

usr = tk.Entry(mainframe)
usr.pack()

tk.Label(mainframe, text="Password").pack()

pwd = tk.Entry(mainframe)
pwd.pack()

tk.Button(mainframe, text="Log in", command=ask_user).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I use computers and different laguages almost 30 years. When I started using Python then I already know how to write code in many other languages - so I needed only Google to find examples for problems which I tried to resolved. Mostly it was problem with files/images/data/web-pages on my own use. The same was with `tkinter`. Currently I check sometimes [documentation for Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm) when I something forget. It is old and incomplet but it is still the most useful page for me.